# Account info for users with local default profile pic show up first in list of all users (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm in the process of building a simple social network app (my first app, so go easy on me) in Android Studio with Firebase. Right now I'm working on an activity that will list all users with profile pic and some basic profile info for each. Some users have a local default profile pic and some have one fetched from Firebase storage. Since it takes longer to get the pictures from storage, all the listings for users with uploaded profile pics show up last on the list. How do I keep this from happening and/or sort the listings? I also want to create a padding textview at the end of the list and I haven't figured out a good way to do this yet.

Here's the code for the search activity:

```
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final int numChildren = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            final Counter counter = new Counter();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                final ImageView profilePic = new ImageView(Search.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.search_image), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.search_image));
                profilePic.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

                if (user.profilePic.isEmpty()) {

                    LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(Search.this);
                    layout2.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.empty));
                    layout2.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
                    layout2.setMinimumWidth(MATCH_PARENT);
                    layout.addView(layout2);
                    profilePic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    layout2.addView(profilePic);

                    LinearLayout layout3 = new LinearLayout(Search.this);
                    layout3.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
                    layout3.setMinimumHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layout3.setMinimumWidth(WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layout2.addView(layout3);

                    TextView un = new TextView(Search.this);
                    un.setText(user.username);
                    un.setTextSize(20);
                    un.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    un.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                    layout3.addView(un);

                    TextView birthYear = new TextView(Search.this);
                    birthYear.setText("Birth Year: " + user.birthYear);
                    birthYear.setTextSize(18);
                    birthYear.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                    layout3.addView(birthYear);

                    TextView gender = new TextView(Search.this);
                    gender.setText("Gender: " + user.gender);
                    gender.setTextSize(18);
                    gender.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                    layout3.addView(gender);

                    TextView location = new TextView(Search.this);
                    location.setText("Location: " + user.location);
                    location.setTextSize(18);
                    location.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                    layout3.addView(location);

                    counter.increment();
                } else {

                    StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                    try {

                        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("profilePic", "jpg");
                        StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child("images/" + snapshot.getKey() + "ProfilePic.jpg");
                        ref.getFile(localFile)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(Search.this);
                                        layout2.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.empty));
                                        layout2.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
                                        layout2.setMinimumWidth(MATCH_PARENT);
                                        layout.addView(layout2);

                                        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.toString());
                                        profilePic.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                                        layout2.addView(profilePic);

                                        LinearLayout layout3 = new LinearLayout(Search.this);
                                        layout3.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
                                        layout3.setMinimumHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);
                                        layout3.setMinimumWidth(WRAP_CONTENT);
                                        layout2.addView(layout3);

                                        TextView un = new TextView(Search.this);
                                        un.setText(user.username);
                                        un.setTextSize(20);
                                        un.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                                        un.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                                        layout3.addView(un);

                                        TextView birthYear = new TextView(Search.this);
                                        birthYear.setText("Birth Year: " + user.birthYear);
                                        birthYear.setTextSize(18);
                                        birthYear.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                                        layout3.addView(birthYear);

                                        TextView gender = new TextView(Search.this);
                                        gender.setText("Gender: " + user.gender);
                                        gender.setTextSize(18);
                                        gender.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                                        layout3.addView(gender);

                                        TextView location = new TextView(Search.this);
                                        location.setText("Location: " + user.location);
                                        location.setTextSize(18);
                                        location.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),0,0,0);
                                        layout3.addView(location);

                                        counter.increment();
                                        if (counter.getCount() == numChildren) {
                                            TextView padding = new TextView(Search.this);
                                            padding.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding),(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding));
                                            layout.addView(padding);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Error downloading image.",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Error creating file.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API call in Firebase Storage to list your files as you mentioned in your post. If you need a functionality like that, you should store the metadata of the files (such as the download URLs) in a place where you can list them. So, you can achieve this with the help of [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). Having all those URLs, will enable you to list your files in every way you want.

Hope it helps.